# Determination of circle given diameter and a point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

I am doing my mathematics homework on circles.
One of the questions asks to find the equation of circle(s) given that it touches the x-axis, passes through $(1, 1)$ and has the line $x + y = 3$ as diameter.
We may solve this question, but while drawing the diagram I asked if only one such circle exists?

My question is to prove the following:

> Given equation of a straight line and an arbitrary point not on the straight line, a unique circle exists such that it passes through the point and the chord cut on the straight line by the circle is its diameter.

Is it really the case or infinite circles pass or does it depend on something?

The point of finding how many circles exist  is that, the question asks to find equation of circle(s). Notice the *(s)*.

Comment: There are exactly 2 circles with its diameter on the line $x+y=3$ that passes through $(1,1)$ and touch the $x$ axis

Comment: How can we prove it in general for a straight line and a point not on it

Comment: What if we shift the center along the diameter by an arbitrary amount, so that now the circle doesn't pass through the arbitrary point; now increase or decrease the radius such that it passes through that arbitrary point. We may repeat this process by increasing the shifts along the diameter and accordingly decrease or increase the radius, and obtain infinite circles. What's wrong in this reasoning?

Comment: The original question you describe includes the condition that the circle "touches" (ie, "is tangent to") the $x$-axis; as commented above, there are two solutions to this case. Your own question omits this condition, and without it, there are indeed infinitely-many solutions: Take the center anywhere you like on the given line, and let the radius be the distance between that center and the given point. (You needn't even require that the point not lie on the line.)

Comment: @Blue oh yes correct... my bad

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The equation of line h passing point $A(1, 1)$ and parallel with line $y+x=3$ is:

$y=-x+2$

it intersect x axis at $B(0, 2)$. The equation of perpendicular bisector of AB is $y=x-1$ and its intersection with line f:$ y+x=3$ is $O(2, 1)$. This is the center of first circle, the radius is $1$ and its equation is :

$(y-1)^2+(x-2)^2=1$

Second circle passes point $A(1, 1)$ and touches x axis at point $L(-2, 0)$. Similarly you can find the equation of perpendicular bisector of AL, it's intersection with line f: $y+x=3$ if point $H(-2, 5)$ and radius is $5$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.- The three points giving the solution are $$\left(\dfrac {\sqrt2}{2}+2,1-\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}\right),\left(\dfrac{-\sqrt2}{2}+2,1+\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}\right),(2,1)$$
I leave you the job of finding them.

[image]

Comment: There's a second solution. The tangency condition effectively describes the circle's center as a point equidistant from the given point and the $x$-axis. The locus of such points is a parabola (with the given point as focus, and the $x$-axis as directrix); this parabola meets the line in two points, each of which is a viable option for the center of the circle.

Comment: @Blue:  I knew that before giving my answer because a commenter had written it. I wanted to give the OP the answer of one solution and ask him to try to find the other. But I forgot. If you want, believe me and if you don't, it doesn't matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, for the answers, they helped me a lot.

One more solution could be:

We have A(1, 1) and let the centre of the circle(s) be C(h, r), where r is radius. We can do this because the circle(s) touch the x-axis.

Now since C lies on x + y = 3, we have

$h = 3 - r$ .......(1)

But, AC = radius (r)

$AC^2 = r^2$

$(h - 1)^2 + (r - 1)^2 = r^2$

$(3 - r - 1)^2 + (r - 1)^2 = r^2$

Solving the quadratic in $r$ we get,
$r = 1$ or $5$.

Corresponding to these, we get $h = 2$ or $- 2$
using the relation (1).

So that, since two distinct solutions of the quadratic equation, there are two circles of centres $(2, 1)$ and $(-2, 5)$.
And their y-coordinates are their radius.

We have the radius and centre of the two circles, which are enough to determine their equations.